# C# using an object as an Type in SQLite for UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm trying to make one function that can take an object as a parameter

```
    public static List<T> Get_DataList_DataFromSystem<T>(object DataNeeded, string BaseTypeString)
    {
          Type baseType = DataNeeded.GetType();
          SQliteConnector.GetInstance.conn.Table<baseType>();
    }
```

using SQliteConnector.GetInstance.conn.Table(); i want to able to use the parameter DataNeeded that is passed into the function.

SQliteConnector.GetInstance gets an instance of the (SQLiteConnection( new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path );)

SQliteConnector.GetInstance.conn.Table(); requires a class to be passed in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic methods require the type to be known at compile time, whereas `GetType()` is executed at runtime.

This is what you're after:

```
public static List<T> Get_DataList_DataFromSystem<T>(T DataNeeded, string BaseTypeString) where T : class
{
      SQliteConnector.GetInstance.conn.Table<T>();
}
```

The type of `DataNeeded` can then be inferred at compile time, based on the type of object that is passed to the method.

Comment: Thank you, after trying this i get the following error
Error CS0452 The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLiteConnection.Table<T>()'

Comment: is their i would add 'where T : class' to the end of the parameters

Comment: @ReeceSmith See my update. That will be because for `Table<T>()`, `T` needs to be a class (rather than an interface / struct etc.), so you need to constrain `T` for `Get_DataList_DataFromSystem` to be a class as well.